# Google Script sometimes not reading full spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, spreadsheet, attachment

I have a spreadsheet that is 862 lines long.  However,  for some reason the below code is only reading the first line of that spreadsheet and thinking that is all that is in there.  This code has worked for years and just started having the problem.  It is not all spreadsheets either,  so I am leaning towards it being a spreadsheet issue,  but the spreadsheets have been created by same process for years as well(no upgrades to either). Any reason why only the first line of the spreadsheet is being read?

I am using the below code snippet:

```
  var threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox in:unread subject:"Test Report"');
  console.log(threads);
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];
  var date = message.getDate();

  // Is the attachment a CSV file
  if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {

    //var meh = attachment.getDataAsString();
    console.log("Printing new data: ", attachment.getDataAsString());
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");
    //var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString());
    console.log(csvData);
  //  console.log(attachment);
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var staging = sheet.getSheetByName("Staging")
    //var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");

    // Remember to clear the content of the sheet before importing new data
    staging.clearContents().clearFormats();
    var date = new Date();
    var dateString = date.toString();
    staging.appendRow(["Last Updated: ", dateString]);
    console.log(csvData.length);
    console.log(csvData[0].length);
    staging.getRange(2, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
   // staging.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
```

I am getting the below results in the log:

D 2020-01-30T16:34:48.955Z Printing new data:  Username,Display Name,AIN,Test Group Name,Test Created Date,Email,Job Title,Department

D 2020-01-30T16:34:48.957Z [[Username, Display Name, AIN, Test Group Name, Test Created Date, Email, Job Title, Department]] 
D 2020-01-30T16:34:49.388Z 1.0 
D 2020-01-30T16:34:49.389Z 8.0

As you can see,  the code is thinking this spreadsheet is only 1 row and 8 columns long,  when it is actually 862 rows and 8 columns. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't see where you're reading the spreadsheet at all.  You clear the staging sheet and write to it but that's it.

Comment: You're clearing the content of the sheet and then writing the data from one attachment. Is the data from the attachment supposed to be 862 rows long?

Comment: sorry for the delay in response.  I actually found the issue.    To clear up your questions first,   I am reading in an email attachment(which is a spreadsheet) and putting those contents into a google sheet.

Comment: The problem was some caching issue with google.  It was reading the wrong attachment,   but the right mail(was archiving and moving the correct mail to the folder after complete) .  Even though it had the right mail,  the attachment in that mail was correct.   The attachment it was reading in was all blanks.   To fix this,  I went and deleted all older mail from any folder(with this subject that the script was looking for) and then emptied my trash.  After I did that,   it started reading the correct attachment from the mail and importing it properly to google sheet.